# How can I disable AnimatePresence animations on initial load?

Tags: framer-motion

I have a bunch of elements that are animated using `AnimatePresence`, but I don't want them animated in during the initial load of my component, only during subsequent interactions with the component. Is there a simple way to disable `AnimatePresence` animations initially and then re-enable them?

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick.

```
<AnimatePresence initial={false}>
```

https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animate-presence/#suppressing-initial-animations